# problem with overloaded method own class (Delphi)

Tags: delphi

I created my own class.
He has overloaded method.

When compiling I get an error:

> E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Create' that can be called with these arguments

```
type    
  TNodeTypeComponent= class(TComponent)    
  public 
    name: string;
    caption: string;
    weight : double;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); reintroduce; overload; 
    constructor Create(name: String; weight : double; AOwner: TComponent); overload;
  end;    
  
constructor TNodeTypeComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent); 
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);  
end;    
 
constructor TNodeTypeComponent.Create(name: String; weight : double; AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  weight:= weight;
  name:= name; 
end;
```

```
type    
  TNodeType<T>= class(TComponent)
  public
    children: array of TNodeType<T>;
    name: string;
    caption: string;
    weight : double;
    type_ : T;
    product:   TNodeTypeProduct;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); overload;
    constructor Create(val : T; AOwner: TComponent); overload; virtual;
    constructor Create(val : T; children: array of TNodeType<T>; AOwner: TComponent); overload; virtual;
  end

constructor TNodeType<T>.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

constructor  TNodeType<T>.Create(val : T; children: array of TNodeType<T>; AOwner: TComponent);    
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

constructor  TNodeType<T>.Create(val : T; AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;
```

MainForm

```
...
else if (json.GetValue('type').Value = 'EComponent') then
begin
  node := TNodeType<TNodeTypeComponent>.Create(
                  TNodeTypeComponent.Create(json.GetValue('name').Value, 
                                            json.GetValue('weight').Value, 
                                            Self), 
                                            Self);
End
...
```

Error in line with 2th `Self`:

```
TNodeTypeComponent.Create(json.GetValue('name').Value, 
                                                json.GetValue('weight').Value, 
                                                Self), 
                                                Self);
```

I can't understand why.

I rename `Create` to `Create_2`, add `override`, `overload`, `virtual`, `reintroduce` - different variations (but I don't fully understand how it works).

Comment: You should always override virtual constructors, which you are not doing here. They virtual TComponent constructor should be overridden. Why do you need an overloaded constructor alongside it? Just for convenience?

Comment: Also, all these scraps of code are annoying and awkward. You'd have had a good answer if you'd just added a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is that when you are calling `json.GetValue('weight').Value`  you are returned string that represents the value of that JSON element but your overridden constructor expects value to be returned as Double.  So either typecast value to Double or change your overridden constructor so that it accepts string type for weight parameter as well.

Comment: @SilverWarior that should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the mentioned error is because Delphi indeed can't find suitable overloaded version of Create.

When you defined your overloaded version of Create the second parameter `weight` is defined as Double type. But when you try to call overloaded version of your constructor for second parameter you call `json.GetValue('weight').Value` which based on [System.JSON.TJSONAncestor.Value](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.JSON.TJSONAncestor.Value) documentation always return String type.

So you will either have to redeclare your overloaded constructor so that it will also be accepting string as second parameter or typecast the return value of `json.GetValue('weight').Value` to Double type.